# How to use particular CSS styles based on screen size / device

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Bootstrap 3 has nice CSS classes in responsive utilities that allow me to hide or show some blocks depending upon the screen resolution  http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes

I have some style rules in a CSS file that I want to be applied or not based on screen resolution.

How can I do it?

I'm going to minimize all my CSS files into the one on production deployment, but this could be avoided if there are no other solutions than having separate CSS files for different screen resolutions.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Use [`@media` queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/). They serve this exact purpose. Here's an example how they work:

```css
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  /* CSS that should be displayed if width is equal to or less than 800px goes here */
}
```

This would work only on devices whose width is equal to or less than 800px.

Read up more about media queries on the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

Comment: Though `media` is used inside HTML to include different CSS files based on the `media` rules. Thanks for pointing it's also can be used inside CSS too.

Comment: If you open up the bootstrap.css file, it is exactly what they have done

Answer (score 25):

Detection is automatic. You must specify what css can be used for each screen resolution:

```
/* for all screens, use 14px font size */
body {  
    font-size: 14px;    
}
/* responsive, form small screens, use 13px font size */
@media (max-width: 479px) {
    body {
        font-size: 13px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

@media queries serve this purpose. Here's an example:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 991px) and (min-width: 769px){
 /* CSS that should be displayed if width is equal to or less than 991px and larger 
  than 768px goes here */
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 991px){
 /* CSS that should be displayed if width is equal to or less than 991px goes here */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I created a little javascript tool to style elements on screen size without using media queries or recompiling bootstrap css:

https://github.com/Heras/Responsive-Breakpoints

Just add class `responsive-breakpoints` to any element, and it will automagically add `xs sm md lg xl` classes to those elements.

Demo: https://codepen.io/HerasHackwork/pen/rGGNEK

Answer (score -1):

Why not use **@media-queries**?
These are designed for that exact purpose.
You can also do this with jQuery, but that's a last resort in my book.

```
var s = document.createElement("script");

//Check if viewport is smaller than 768 pixels
if(window.innerWidth < 768) {
    s.type = "text/javascript";
    s.src = "http://www.example.com/public/assets/css1";
}else { //Else we have a larger screen
    s.type = "text/javascript";
    s.src = "http://www.example.com/public/assets/css2";
}

$(function(){
    $("head").append(s); //Inject stylesheet
})
```