# Bootstrap: How to apply certain CSS rules, when on different devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can someone apply certain CSS rules when viewed in different screen sizes in bootstrap?
Like, when viewed in md, Any element's left-margin should be 10px. And when viewed in sm, the same should be 100px.
Thanks.

Comment: What you're looking for are CSS Media Queries.

Comment: I created a little tool to automagically add screen size classes (xs sm md lg xl) to elements so you can actually style your elements like that without caring about media query pixels or recompiling bootstrap css: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46654262/263533

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is right out of bootstrap... using the media query.  Is this what you are refferring to?

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .jumbotron {
    padding-top: 48px;
    padding-bottom: 48px;
  }
  .container .jumbotron {
    padding-right: 60px;
    padding-left: 60px;
  }
  .jumbotron h1,
  .jumbotron .h1 {
    font-size: 63px;
  }
}
```