# Horizontal vs Vertical navbar based on screen size

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm redesigning a web page for a friend and I'm trying to eliminate a bunch of white space on larger screens. One way that I've though of doing this is by taking one of the static nav bars and making it vertical on larger screens and flipping to horizontal on smaller screens. I'm not sure what kind of code would be needed to do this. Could it be done solely with css or would this have to be accomplished with JS/C#?

I already have each version of the navbar developed its a matter of when each is displayed. See attached photos.

[image: Horizontal Navbar (SmallerScreens)[1]]
[image: Vertical Navbar (Larger Screens)]

Comment: This [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21076033/10552687) may help. @media queries are useful for this

Answer (score 1):

One solution I would highly recommend is flexbox and media queries.

[See this CSS-tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-direction/)

Use flex-direction: row for your horizontal navbar, and flex-direction: column for your vertical navbar. You can use a media query to swap between column and row flex direction based on the screen width. The media query code you are looking for is something like this:

```
.navbar {
  display: flex
}

/* On screens that are 992px or less, set navbar to horizontal */
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .navbar {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

[Have a look at more media query examples on w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp)

Comment: This is also my preferred solution. I would only make one small change .navbar {display: flex; flex-direction: row;} just to be explicit.