# Changing css with Jquery in different screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This code is working properly when I remove the `if() {}` but I want the css style to work just for specific window widths. When I add the `if` statement it doesn't read the CSS style anymore. Any idea why?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".icon").mousemove(function() {
      $(this).hide();
      $(".second").show(2000);
      if (windows.innerWidth > 768) {
        $(".second").css({
          "display": "grid",
          "grid-template": "200px / 200px 200px"
        });
      }
   });    
});


I also tried this and still not working:

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".icon").mousemove(function() {

        $(this).hide();
        $(".second").show(2000);
        if ($(window).width() > 768){
          $(".second").css({
            "display": "grid",
            "grid-template": "200px / 200px 200px"
             });
        }

        else {
          $(".second").css({
            "display": "grid",
            "grid-template": "100px / 100px 100px"
             });
        }

        });
    
    });
```

Comment: you can use media queries.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use particular CSS styles based on screen size / device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21075983/how-to-use-particular-css-styles-based-on-screen-size-device)

Comment: Can you add a snippet of a working example with your problem? And what did you mean by `it doesn't read the CSS style anymore`?

Answer (score 0):

inside of your css file, you can use a media query like this.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .second{
        display: grid;
        grid-template: 200px / 200px 200px;
    }
}
```

[Learn more about media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media)

Comment: thank you, but i am looking to make it in Javascript

Comment: Can you please make your code block in your question a snippet and provide more than just js.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $(window).width() function to get windows width.

```
if ($(window).width() > 768) {

 // write you css here for screen size is more then 768
}else{

// write you css here for screen size is less then 768
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code, To Changing CSS with Jquery in different screen size

```
<div id="outer-div">
    <div id="inner-div">
    <H2>Switch CSS On Window Resize</H2>
    </div>
    <div id="menu-div">
    <H2>Tags</H2>
    <a class="demo-tag">Fluid</a>
    <a class="demo-tag">Stylesheet</a>
    <a class="demo-tag">Resize</a>
    <a class="demo-tag">Demo</a>
    <a class="demo-tag">Examples</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript and Jquery:

```
<script>
    function switchCSS(windowsize) {
      if (windowsize > 800) {
        $("#switchable").attr("href", "web.css");
      } else {
         $("#switchable").attr("href", "mobile.css"); 
      }
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
      switchCSS($(this).width());
      
      $(window).resize(function() {
        switchCSS($(this).width());
      });
    });
</script>
```

I hope this code will be useful to you.

Thank you.