# Is there a way in html to choose the page with the best resolution?

Tags: html, resize, autoresize

I created a website in html that looks good on a computer, but bad on a phone. I then created a separate page that looked good on phones, but bad on computers.
Is there a way using html, css or javascript that I can have the website switch between the two html codes to best match the resolution of the user's device?

Comment: Twitter bootstrap([a .css file](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.css)) is the easiest way to make a webpage be more or less acceptable various screen sizes and can work without javascript. Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21075983/how-to-use-particular-css-styles-based-on-screen-size-device. You shouldn't need to have two completely different webpages for different devices, but this can be done too with javascript.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.